# How do I find Image resource while doing web performance test

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, web-performance

I am creating Web performance test for an Angular Application using Visual Studio, which contains image logo. I’m receiving an error like: “No resource found” related to that image logo after recording its web URL, while testing that URL as shown in the below picture. Can you give any suggestion for this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have the link to the image as

```
app/home/app/assets/images/AzureAppServiceLogo.png
```

notice that **app** is in the absolute path twice, and this is probably what's causing the 404 error.

Let me know if this resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's not resolved yet. Why because, the Azure portal can't recognizing the local path for that Logo.

Comment: did you set whether my suggestion fixes the issue ?